# Button Command get not fired

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a strange situation.
I working on an App for WINRT and have some problems with a command binding. This is the part of the xaml:

```
    <control:ItemsHub ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
        <control:ItemsHub.SectionHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding CategoryNavigationCommand}" Margin="5,0,0,10" Content="{Binding Header}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </control:ItemsHub.SectionHeaderTemplate>
    </control:ItemsHub>
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
    public CategorySectionViewModel(IRecipeService recipeService, INavigationService navigationService, RecipeTreeItemDto treeItem)
    {
        ...
        CategoryNavigationCommand = new DelegateCommand(NavigateToCategory);
        ...
    }


    private string _header;

    public string Header
    {
        get { return _header; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _header, value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand CategoryNavigationCommand { get; private set; }


    private void NavigateToCategory()
    {
        _navigationService.Navigate("CategoryHub", _recipeTreeItemDto.NodePath);
    }
```

**I don't get any binding errors in the output window and also the "Header" gets shown in the Button. But the Command won't get fired wenn i click on it! What i'm doing wrong?**

Maybe it is because i created a custom HubControl. With this control i'm able to attach an ItemSource and ItemTemplate for the HubSection-Header and the HubSection-Content. Maybe because of this some bindings getting lost?

Here is my custom hub control:

```
public class ItemsHub : Hub
{
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public HubSection SpotlightSection
    {
        get { return (HubSection)GetValue(SpotlightSectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SpotlightSectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public DataTemplate SectionHeaderTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(SectionHeaderTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SectionHeaderTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ItemsHub), new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemTemplateChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList), typeof(ItemsHub), new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemsSourceChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SpotlightSectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SpotlightSection", typeof(HubSection), typeof(ItemsHub), new PropertyMetadata(default(HubSection), SpotlightSectionChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SectionHeaderTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SectionHeaderTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ItemsHub), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplate), HeaderTemplateChanged));

    private static void SpotlightSectionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsHub hub = d as ItemsHub;
        if (hub != null)
        {
            bool hubContainsSpotLight = hub.Sections.Contains(hub.SpotlightSection);
            if (hub.SpotlightSection != null && !hubContainsSpotLight)
            {
                hub.Sections.Add(hub.SpotlightSection);
            }
            if (hub.SpotlightSection == null && hubContainsSpotLight)
            {
                hub.Sections.Remove(hub.SpotlightSection);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void HeaderTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsHub hub = d as ItemsHub;
        if (hub != null)
        {
            DataTemplate template = e.NewValue as DataTemplate;
            if (template != null)
            {
                // Apply template
                foreach (var section in hub.Sections.Except(new List<HubSection> { hub.SpotlightSection }))
                {
                    section.HeaderTemplate = template;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ItemTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsHub hub = d as ItemsHub;
        if (hub != null)
        {
            DataTemplate template = e.NewValue as DataTemplate;
            if (template != null)
            {
                // Apply template
                foreach (var section in hub.Sections.Except(new List<HubSection> { hub.SpotlightSection }))
                {
                    section.ContentTemplate = template;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsHub hub = d as ItemsHub;
        if (hub != null)
        {
            IList items = e.NewValue as IList;
            if (items != null)
            {
                var spotLightSection = hub.SpotlightSection;
                hub.Sections.Clear();

                if (spotLightSection != null)
                {
                    hub.Sections.Add(spotLightSection);
                }

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    HubSection section = new HubSection();
                    section.DataContext = item;
                    section.Header = item;
                    DataTemplate headerTemplate = hub.SectionHeaderTemplate;
                    section.HeaderTemplate = headerTemplate;

                    DataTemplate contentTemplate = hub.ItemTemplate;
                    section.ContentTemplate = contentTemplate;

                    hub.Sections.Add(section);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try using 

    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CategoryNavigationCommand}

Comment: @jcrada Then i become a binding error (Error: BindingExpression path error: 'DataContext' property not found on 'WinRTApp.ViewModels.CategorySectionViewModel, WinRTApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='DataContext.CategoryNavigationCommand' DataItem='WinRTApp.ViewModels.CategorySectionViewModel, WinRTApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' (Name='null'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand'))

Comment: Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CategoryNavigationCommand}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type localSource:ItemsHub}} localSource should be defined as xmlns:localSource="clr-namespace:MyProject.library"

Comment: AncestorType is not available in WinRT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution! I don't know why but the section header of a hub control is not interactive by default! So i have to set the interactivity to true when i assign the itemsource in my custom ItemHub-Control.

Here is what i changed in the ItemsHub Control:

```
    private static void ItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsHub hub = d as ItemsHub;
        if (hub != null)
        {
            IList items = e.NewValue as IList;
            if (items != null)
            {
                var spotLightSection = hub.SpotlightSection;
                hub.Sections.Clear();

                if (spotLightSection != null)
                {
                    hub.Sections.Add(spotLightSection);
                }

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    HubSection section = new HubSection();
                    DataTemplate headerTemplate = hub.SectionHeaderTemplate;
                    section.HeaderTemplate = headerTemplate;

                    DataTemplate contentTemplate = hub.ItemTemplate;
                    section.ContentTemplate = contentTemplate;

                    section.DataContext = item;
                    section.Header = item;

                    //This line fixed my problem.
                    section.IsHeaderInteractive = true;

                    hub.Sections.Add(section);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following binding expression

Command="{Binding CategoryNavigationCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=XYX}}"

and XYZ is a control type in which you have placed ItemsHub

Comment: I don't think AncestorType is available in WinRT/XAML.

Comment: True Story... AncestorType is not available in WINRT :(